# How does gradle package a jar (internally)?

Tags: gradle, npm, build, jar, zip

I'm usually not the type of person to give the first flying f... about how my beloved black boxes work on the inside as long as everyone purrs in unison.

But recently I've been met with the following error

`Problem creating jar: archive contains more than 65535 entries`

Thing is : for the exact same project it worked on a machine but not the other ...

I know how to fix the damn problem but I'm left there wondering why said-solution is necessary on one machine and not the other.

I don't want an answer specific to my case but more generally : what could cause different outcomes for a same build, launched in the same way on two machines ?

- Does gradle have os-dependent implementations of the jar plugin ?
- Does it tend to use the system's zip software to compress the jar if it can ?
- Is there an hard limit on my specific machine because I cursed at gradle and now it's mad ?
- Could it be something else during the build that produces more files on certain machines (like an `npm install` *(don't judge me I didn't make the project I merely work on it)*) ?

Comment: Ok, so in my exact case, it turns out that someone (feeling very smart) made changes in the expected build process based on some very specific details, and me being the usual sticking out nail, I ended up taking extra steps in the build ...
But I still knida wanna know if gradle relies on the machines implementation of zip or if it comes packed with it's own zip implementation :)